# makefile compile with gcc UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

Trying to make `makefile` to turn all .c into execute files in directory.
For example:

```
am.c
2.c
s.c
```

into

```
am
2
s
```

programs.

Anything works,but it uses `cc`, but I want to use `gcc` compiler.
How can I do that?

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
BIN = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRC))

all : $(BIN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line to the top saying

```
CC = gcc
```

Comment: thanks,and one more question.do you know how to add libraries `-L/usr/lib/nptl -lpthread -lsocket -lnsl -lrt` in it? compile with that

Comment: You will have to add some rules to do that.  A very lame method will be to specify CC = gcc -L/usr/lib/nptl -lpthread -lsocket -lnsl -lrt but somebody is going to flame me for even suggesting that :-)

Comment: @unxnut: NO!! WTH are you suggesting @#$@#$  :P, small suggestion maybe you can mention `CC := gcc` which will override `CC` variable only in case it is not set in the environment. It may be possible to have `make` use `gcc` by issuing `CC=gcc make`. @Alex Gray: Actually you can make use of `CFLAGS` & `LDFLAGS` variables. `CFLAGS` are meant for compilation time flags & `LDFLAGS` for link-time. Add `CFLAGS = -L/usr/lib/nptl` & `LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lsocket -lnsl -lrt`. If this answer has helped you solve your problem, please accept it. Thank you

Comment: Oops, nother.anon.coward has a better suggestion than mine.  However, `CFLAGS` is meant to inform the compiler about compile time options such as `-g` or `-ansi`.  May be you can add both library location and  the libraries by using `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Sorry my bad! Both `-L` & `-l` option should be part of `LDFLAGS` (Dammit can't edit the comment, too much text effort to delete :P)